# Converting to date with multiple possible masks in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, to-date

It so happens that I have to get a date from a varchar2 column in oracle, but it is inconsistent in formatting. Some fields might have '2009.12.31', others '2009/12/32 00:00:00'. Is there any standard construct I could use, so that I don't have to go through

```
begin
  to_date(date, mask1)
exception
  begin
    to_date(date,mask2)
  exception
    ..
  end
end
```

blocks or prior date string analysis to determine the correct mask? Something like `to_date(date, mask1,mask2,..)` ?

Comment: Sounds like there are no restrictions on what gets entered into that Varchar2 field.  How do you handle the situation where what is entered is not a valid date string at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but some Oracle date formats are "forgiving" of differences e.g.

```
SQL> select to_date('2009.12.31','YYYY/MM/DD') from dual;

TO_DATE('20
-----------
31-DEC-2009
```

So that may reduce the amount of cases you need to handle.  I suggest you write a function along the lines you were thinking of, so that it can be called from all the places in your code where you need to handle dates like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enumerate all the possible formats you want to support - remember that some are ambiguous (e.g. is "10-11-2009" 10 Nov or Oct 11?) so your code will have to favour one over the other.

As Tony has said, some formats will accept a variety of inputs, mainly in regards to parsing of separator characters and missing bits (e.g. 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' will match '31-DEC-2009 10:30:00', '31/deC/2009 10:30', '31 dec  2009').

Apart from these simplifications, you're going to need a series of BEGIN (format1) EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN BEGIN (format2) EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN BEGIN ....